# Different response of min() and max() to separate data

Tags: python

I am having a strange ( beginner) problem:

`val1`, `val2`, `val3` are 3 separate `int` values ( from separate computations )

`min(val1,val2,val3)` returns the correct minimum

`max(val1,val2,val3)` fails with

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Somehow I am afraid I overloaded the `max` definition, but not sure how or where.

Comment: maybe you did `max = some_value` in computations and you override function `max()`

Comment: check `print(max)` if you get integer value then you overrided function. You can try `del max` to return to function definition.

Comment: could you post here the chunk of code that is giving you problems?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you override `max()` function in your computations.

You can check it

```
print( type(max) )
```

and you should get:

- for function

  ```
  <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
  ```
- for integer value

  ```
  <class 'int'>
  ```

But you can reset it

```
del max
```